# Create folder in Sql Server management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I group my stored procedure under folders in Sql server management studio 2008, Can I group and move related stored procedure to it.This should maintain the structure during database backup also.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server/SSMS does not have this functionality. However, you can use [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) (ideally with source control integration) to organize database objects to your liking independently of the physical database deployment(s).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **you can't**.

You can upvote the [microsoft connect suggestion for that](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/209340), even though it is closed as "won't fix".

There are paid SSMS addins that will do that, though not exactly how you describe it:

- [SQLTreeo](https://www.sqltreeo.com/)
- [SQL Handy Groupie](http://www.skilledsoftware.com/)

If you are looking for a way to find database objects quickly, some free alternatives would be:

- [RedGate's Sql Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)
- [ApexSql's Sql Object Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx)